# Character Controller and Reverse Gravity

Tags: unity, c#, physics, 3d

So I have a Game object with Rigid Body, a Character controller and my Movement script. On a specific condition I am reversing gravity. The problem is that the velocity.Y when the gravity is reversed, keeps increasing to the infinity. If I try to reset it like in the first if statement (which works for normal gravity) the object keeps bouncing from the ground. Gravity scale is either 1 or -1 in order to reverse gravity and movement.

This is the code:

```
 void Update()
    {
        
        _isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.4f, whatIsGround);
        Move();
    }

void Move(){
//Reseting States for new cycle , unless the object is falling
        if ((_isGrounded && velocity.y < 0))
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
            _isRunning = false;
            _isJumping = false;
            _isFalling = false;
        }else if (velocity.y < 0 && !_isGrounded)
        {
            _isFalling = true;
        }
        //Moving on X axis
        float x = Input.GetAxis(KeyInputMove);
        if (x != 0)
        {
            _isRunning = true;
        }
        moveDirection = gravityScale*_transform.right * x;
        _controller.Move(moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Perfoming jump
        if (Input.GetButtonDown(KeyInputJump) && _isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = (float) Math.Sqrt(1 * -2f * globalGravity);
            _isJumping = true;
        }
        
        velocity.y += gravityScale * globalGravity * Time.deltaTime;
        _controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
//Updating animation states 
        _animator.SetBool("Grounded",_isGrounded);//^This is the idle state
        _animator.SetBool("Running",_isRunning);
        _animator.SetBool("Jumping",_isJumping);
        _animator.SetBool("Falling",_isFalling);

    }
    
   
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
       //Reverse Gravity and Model Rotation
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Portal")
        {
            _transform.Rotate(0,0,gravityScale*180);
            gravityScale *= -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the velocity.Y when the gravity is reversed , keeps increasing to the infinity.

That's what your code tells it to do:

`velocity.y += gravityScale * globalGravity * Time.deltaTime;`

Perhaps you are forgetting to check if the gravity is negative or positive when determining whether the object is falling. Here's what you probably want:

```
if (gravityScale > 0 && velocity.y < 0) 
    || (gravityScale < 0 && velocity.y > 0)) 
{
    _isFalling = true;
} else {
    _isFalling = false;
}

if (_isGrounded && _isFalling) {
    velocity.y = -2f * gravityScale; //maybe you should just set it to 0?
    _isRunning = false;
    _isJumping = false;
    _isFalling = false;
}
```

I assume that `gravityScale` is 1 when gravity is normal (objects fall downward) and -1 when gravity is reversed (objects fall upward?). I'm not really sure why you are setting the velocity to -2 in the first `if` condition; you might want to try setting it to 0.

Comment: Yes this is exactly how `gravityScale` works. The velocity setting (-2 or 0) doesnt really matter. I followed Brackeys tutorial and he set it to -2 which works and doesnt really affect. This condition resets the Velocity and stays stable. I tried your code and it doesnt work. Also it doesnt make sense , since the object cant be `_isGrounded` and `isFalling` at the same time. 
I agree that the `velocity.y += gravityScale * globalGravity * Time.deltaTime;` is the line making the increment , but this is why we use the `if` to keep the velocity stable when the player isnt jumping or falling.

Comment: Have a look to the inspector in the velocity values , when above and when bellow.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9P50ONdOp5fepuQitC7V4Ym2zE_6yPS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ThanosLoupas You're right, I had a couple of mistakes. Try it now.

Comment: I did and this is the result : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVIiBqLCgmqM9rAPt2QlX7DvkHE-hPSg/view?usp=sharing
Note that I am not pressing jump , it just happens. This is the bouncing effect I stated at first.

Comment: @ThanosLoupas Please add the code that sets `_isGrounded` to your question.

Comment: `_isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.4f, whatIsGround);`
This works propely.

Comment: @ThanosLoupas I don't see any reason for this to happen in your code. My best guess at this point is you have some other code that you haven't shared that is changing the object's position, perhaps when it collides with something or becomes grounded.

Comment: @ThanosLoupas Please edit your question and show all of your code, instead of mentioning missing code in the comments.

Comment: I updated , with the collision code and the update function

Comment: @ThanosLoupas Thanks. At the bottom of your script you change some bools in the Animator. I'd guess that one of these animations is moving the object downward when it becomes grounded.

Comment: You are right !!! It solved the weird bouncing effect. The only problem now is that I cannot perform jump when the player is on the down side.

Comment: I found it. I modified jump with `velocity.y*= -1; ` when on down side. That's all ! We did it. Thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: @ThanosLoupas Great, glad to help.